# How to use command to delete folders in FTP?

Tags: linux, ftp

Suppose there are some folders on FTP site:

```
test_20160125,test_20160222
```

I use the command to delete the specific folders on FTP:

```
ftp> rm *test_*

550 The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

How can I delete the folders using FTP command?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 6):

The `ftp(1)` command-line client translates its built-in `rm` command into the FTP `DELE` command, and most FTP servers handle `DELE` (**DELE**te File) by calling the function for deleting a *file* (*e.g.* `unlink(2)` on Unix), not a directory.  Thus you might try:

```
ftp> rmdir *test_*
```

However, even the above would probably fail, as the client-side `rmdir` command would be translated to the FTP `RMD` (**R**e**M**ove **D**irectory) command; many FTP servers handle `RMD` by calling *e.g.* the `rmdir(2)` function.  Some FTP servers would *not* handle the `RMD` parameter as a glob pattern, and thus might try to delete a directory named *exactly* "*test_*" (which presumably does not exist).  And even if the glob pattern *was* handled, attempting to delete a directory which contains files often fails; the files in the directory need to be deleted first.

Thus you might need to delete the files in those directories, *then* delete the directories themselves:

```
ftp> mdelete test_*/*
```

The client-side `mdelete` command should, behind the scenes, do the necessary glob/pattern matching for you, and delete the files matching the pattern.  Then you might remove those directories using:

```
ftp> rmdir test_20160125
ftp> rmdir test_20160222
```

Since functionality of this nature is often done in the client, using a more sophisticated FTP client such as `lftp`, as suggested by @User123, can be much easier.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Use **lftp** protocol, also use `rm -r` where `r` option delete files and directories recursively.

```
$ lftp -u <user>,<pass> <server> 
lftp> rm -r <directory>
```

Comment: I use lftp and use cd to change the remote directory, but I got the message: "cd: Access failed: 550 Access is denied". How to change directory using cd ?

Comment: lcd can change local directory but can not change remote directory. Is there any way to change remote directory normally without access denied?

Comment: Reference link : http://www.ducea.com/2006/07/27/allowing-ftp-access-to-files-outside-the-home-directory-chroot/

Answer (score 1):

Use LFTP with

> glob -a rm -r ...

links :

- http://www.sanitarium.co.za/delete-multiple-remote-files-and-directories-via-ftp/
- https://blog.droidzone.in/2013/02/13/lftp-recursively-delete-a-non-empty-directory